# I wasn’t meant to do something. // I didn’t mean to do something

Tags: tense, passive-voice

> 1. I **wasn’t meant** to do something.
> 2. I **didn’t mean** to do something.

How different they are from each other?

Comment: They are very different. The first one means that doing that thing would go against the intentions of someone (your boss) or something (fate) that is supposed to have control over you. The second one means that you did not do that thing intentionally. If you say the first one, we don't know whether you did it or not, but if you say the second one we know you did do it.

Comment: I have seen my friend status on his facebook "We weren't meant to end like this" Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the first meaning probably fits that situation.

Comment: @user96060 this is a good answer and you should express it as an answer, not just a comment!

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means *other people* didn't expect you to do something, while the second one means *you* had no intention to do that something.